# Data showing up in ListView that's not in bound database

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I'm storing incoming data directly to a SQLite database. The data is displayed in a ListView using a subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter. Everything works fine.

Now I'm in the middle of transitioning to a ContentProvider and the original data no longer shows up in the ListView but new incoming data is displayed. Opening the corresponding database, I see the original data (which doesn't appear) but not the new data.

In Debug Expressions, it appears that the data bound to the ListView comes from the path/name of the database I opened, which is stored in the default databases directory.

So where's the new data stored and coming from?

There are 2 other files in the databases folder: Scores-shm, Scores-wal, neither of which I can open. Could write-ahead logging be the culprit? I've looked at the SQLite docs but I'm not sure how to proceed or if this is even the right track to pursue.